# TFS 2015 build error

Tags: team-foundation-server

Good afternoon,

I've been tasked with finding out how to fix errors that are keeping TFS from being completely successful in our builds.

I was initially under the impression that it was a security permission error, but I have added permissions for the TFS user account to ensure access to all the necessary drives.  I enabled verbose mode in the error log and have received the following:

```
Starting task: Publish Artifact: drop
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\Agent\tasks\CopyPublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.20\CopyPublishBuildArtifacts.ps1
Preparing artifact content in staging folder C:\Agent\_work\1\a...
**System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid.**

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.CopyBuildArtifactCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I've reviewed MSDN, and I haven't found anything that addresses this error in even a roundabout fashion.
Can someone explain how the directory name can be invalid when the file listed is the one that TFS created when I created the agent?  I'm willing to provide any additional information that might be necessary.
I appreciate anybody who has stuck through this wall of text.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b88408db-194c-407e-8b4f-f71cfbb0c703/build-error?forum=tfsbuild#a9ddf632-2c34-46d0-992e-4c93b3d0ffb7

A very helpful individual in MSDN pointed out that my copy root value had to be a folder, not a specific file.  Once I fixed that error, it worked like a charm.